# How to access variable from spinner listener?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, in which I want to access 'selectedTeam' at the button listener.

```
        //Adding setOnItemSelectedListener method on spinner.
        sTeams.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                selectedTeam = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                editText.setText(selectedTeam, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        buttonApply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String editedName = editText.getText().toString();
                // Here I want to access selectedTeam
            }
        });
```

I tried to declare the variable outside the method but that gives the error 'Variable 'selectedTeam'is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final'. I tried that, but that doesn't work since final Strings cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *class member* instead.

In [JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e9337):

> When an inner class (whose declaration does not occur in a static
>   context) refers to an instance variable that is a member of a
>   lexically enclosing class, the variable of the corresponding lexically
>   enclosing instance is used.
>
> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but
>   not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

It means you can only use an *outside* `final` variable or an *enclosing class member* in an *anonymous* inner class.

```
[...]
private String selectedTeam;
[...]

//Adding setOnItemSelectedListener method on spinner.
    sTeams.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            selectedTeam = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            editText.setText(selectedTeam, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    buttonApply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String editedName = editText.getText().toString();
            if (selectedTeam != null && !"".equals(selectedTeam)) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I now understand, though I don't yet know how to solve my problem. how do I access 'selectedTeam' from outside the method?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I edited to `selectedTeam`. `selectedTeam` is now enclosing class member so you can access it inside and outside your anonymous class.

Comment: @no-name Please note no more `selectedTeam` declaration outside to prevent the shadowing issue or you just simply use `ClassName.this.selectedTeam` instead of `selectedTeam` in your inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable global.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String selectedteam;
...
buttonApply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String editedName = editText.getText().toString();
            selectedteam = editedName; // or whatever you want
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use shared preference to store the value and get that value where i want to use.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "selectedTeam");
editor.apply();
```

**How to get value:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("name", null);
```

Hope it helps